# Finding ad status in google IMA ads (Completed or Skipped)?

Tags: javascript, ads, adsense, google-dfp

I need to find weather the ad is skipped or completed. Also started or loaded and or clicked. I am confused with the google's dev docs. I need to get some thing like this,

```
if (google.ima.AdEvent.Type.COMPLETE){
    console.log("Ad has been completed")
}
```

If anything like this is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google.ima.AdEvent includes "SKIPPED" and "COMPLETE", among many others (see [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/reference/js/google.ima.AdEvent) for full reference list). You can track each of these adEvent.type using and event listener attached to the adsManager instance (details [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/reference/js/google.ima.AdsManager)) :

```
//get ads manager
adsManager = adsManagerLoadedEvent.getAdsManager(
        videoContent, adsRenderingSettings); 

//add eventlistener
adsManager.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.LOADED, onAdEvent);
adsManager.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.SKIPPED, onAdEvent);
adsManager.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.STARTED, onAdEvent);
adsManager.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.COMPLETE, onAdEvent);

//adEvent function
function onAdEvent(adEvent) {
  var ad = adEvent.getAd();
  switch (adEvent.type) {
    case  google.ima.AdEvent.Type.LOADED:
      console.log('loaded');
      break;
    case  google.ima.AdEvent.Type.STARTED:
      console.log('started');
      break;
    case  google.ima.AdEvent.Type.COMPLETE:
      console.log('complete');
      break;
    case  google.ima.AdEvent.Type.SKIPPED:
      console.log('skipped');
      break;
  }
}
```

You can download working and detailed samples [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/download) (see the "simple" one in particular).

Comment: try moving the proposed script inside the function onAdsManagerLoded() right after adsManager has been declared...